# Magic link auth issue in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, sdk

I am trying to implement direct login on magic-link click

How it works:

1. - On click login we call magic.auth.loginWithMagicLink
   - And pass email and redirect URI

```
if (email) {
   await magic.auth.loginWithMagicLink({ email, redirectURI: ${window.location.origin}/callback });
}
```

---

2. RedirectURI is /callback page where we take “magic_credential” from url and pass it to magic.auth.loginWithCredential

```
    const { magic_credential = null } = router.query;

    if (magic_credential) {
      const magic = new Magic(process.env.MAGIC_PUBLIC_KEY);
      await magic.auth.loginWithCredential(magic_credential);
    }

   initMagic(); // fetch userMetada via magic and error appears here like user is not auth
```

---

As result we get this error:

> initMagic start Error: Magic RPC Error: [-32603] Internal error: User
> denied account access.

It looks like I am not authenticated and inside of `initMagic()` I am fetching some user data and get this error

Do you know what may be the problem?